# checking database value every second while allowing user to do other things

Tags: c#, asp.net, multithreading, web-applications

I need a process that every second checks if a value from database is true, this is set to true by a windows service.

when the value is true update an image.
but i need that while the value is false, the user is free to do other activities in page.

I have been looking for multithreading communication, but i really don't found something for the specific need I have.

Thanks for your help

Here i'm adding the code I have:

```
private static class QuickUpdateCompletedCheck
{
    #region BEGIN Declares

    private static ProcessStatus quickUpdateCompletedStatus;
    private static Thread quickUpdateThread;
    private static ISynchronizeInvoke quickUpdateCompletedSynch;
    private static bool updateCompleted;
    private static QuickUpdateInfo quickUpdateInfo = null;

    public delegate void UpdateCompletedStatusCheck(string Message, int status);

    #endregion END Declares
    #region BEGIN Initialization

    public QuickUpdateCompletedCheck(ISynchronizeInvoke syn, ProcessStatus notify, Guid userIdLoc, int activityIdLoc, int fileIdLoc, int spreadIdLoc)
    {
        quickUpdateCompletedSynch = syn;
        quickUpdateCompletedStatus = notify;
        quickUpdateInfo = new QuickUpdateInfo(activityIdLoc, fileIdLoc, spreadIdLoc, userIdLoc);
    }

    #endregion END Initialization
    #region BEGIN Methods

    public void StartProcess()
    {
        quickUpdateThread = new System.Threading.Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(UpdateStatus));
        //set the thread to run in the background
        quickUpdateThread.IsBackground = true;
        //name our thread (optional)
        quickUpdateThread.Name = "Add List Items Thread";
        //start our thread
        quickUpdateThread.Start();
    }

    private static void UpdateStatus(object data)
    {
        QuickUpdateInfo quickUpdateInfo = (QuickUpdateInfo)data;

        object[] dataInfo = new object[4];

        dataInfo[0] = quickUpdateInfo.ActivityId;
        dataInfo[1] = quickUpdateInfo.FileId;
        dataInfo[2] = quickUpdateInfo.SpreadId;
        dataInfo[3] = quickUpdateInfo.UserId;

        quickUpdateCompletedSynch.Invoke(QuickUpdateCompletedataInfo); //Here I have an error need a delegate method in first parameter. i suppose is the QuickUpdateComplete method at the end of this description
    }

    #endregion END Methods
}

public class QuickUpdateInfo
{
    private int activityId;
    private int fileId;
    private int spreadId;
    private Guid userId;

    public int ActivityId
    {
        get { return activityId; }
    }

    public int FileId
    {
        get { return fileId; }
    }

    public int SpreadId
    {
        get { return spreadId; }
    }

    public Guid UserId
    {
        get { return userId; }
    }

    public QuickUpdateInfo(int activityId, int fileId, int spreadId, Guid userId)
    {
        this.activityId = activityId;
        this.fileId = fileId;
        this.spreadId = spreadId;
        this.userId = userId;
    }
}
```

this methods are in the page the image most be updated

```
public partial class SpreadCorrection : BasePage
{
        protected void UpdatePostBack_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
                //how to start Thread here
    }

    private static void QuickUpdateComplete(int activityId, int fileId, int spreadId)
    {
        if (value from database is true)
        {   
                    UpdateImage();
                    //how to stop Thread here
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: *Why* doesn't multi threading work for you?

Comment: Do you really think you are the first one who's faced with this kind of problem and really nothing at internet? I interpret  this question as: *I am too lazy to read all those stuff, post me a working solution*

Comment: well multi-threading i thing is the answear but i have tryed several examples. Anyway thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use JavaScript's `setInterval()` function and jQuery's `.ajax()` function to call a service on the server-side to check for a value, like this:

```
function checkForDatabaseValue() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "YourPage.aspx/GetDatabaseValue",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        data: "{}",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
            // Do something with data returned here
        },
        error: function (errorMessage) {
            // Do something with error message here
        },
        complete: function() {
            // Reset the timer to a minute here
            setTimeout(function() { 
                checkForDatabaseValue(); 
            }, 60000);
        }
    });
}
```

`YourPage.aspx` can host an ASP.NET AJAX Page Method to do simple page hosted service that automatically encode to JSON data, like this:

```
[WebMethod]
public static string GetDatabaseValue()
{
    // Put database retrieval logic here
}
```

Note: You will need a reference to the ASP.NET AJAX library to use Page Methods. The above `setInterval` and `.ajax()` calls will work with ASP.NET XML Web Services (.asmx) and WCF services as well, but I showed the ASP.NET AJAX Page Method approach, because of its simplicity.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways of running background thread in ASP.Net.

Here is a simple example for ASP.Net - [Easy Background Tasks in ASP.NET](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/07/easy-background-tasks-in-aspnet/)

It'll call your code in the specified interval (currently 30 seconds) by using cache.

```
void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    AddTask("DoStuff", 30); // 30 seconds
}

private static CacheItemRemovedCallback OnCacheRemove;

private void AddTask(string name, int seconds)
{
    OnCacheRemove = CacheItemRemoved;

    HttpRuntime.Cache.Insert(name, seconds, null, 
        DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(seconds), Cache.NoSlidingExpiration,
        CacheItemPriority.NotRemovable, OnCacheRemove);
}

public void CacheItemRemoved(string k, object v, CacheItemRemovedReason r)
{
    // Checks if a value from database is true. 
    // If so, call to your method here ...

    AddTask(k, Convert.ToInt32(v));
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. This is my first time i'm working with threading. I've added the code i have to the question so you can see if I'm in the way or what i'm doing not good. thanks again